# How to extract string difference between two series in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, text, diff

I am trying to create a new pandas column that contains a diff between two other columns.

what I have:
colA            | colB              |
this is test    | this is a testing |

What I want
colA            | colB              | colC
this is test    | this is a testing | this is a ____

This is the code I have so far

```
def tokenize(s):
    return re.split('\s+', s)

def untokenize(ts):
    return ' '.join(ts)

def equalize(s1, s2):
    l1 = tokenize(s1)
    l2 = tokenize(s2)
    res1 = []
    res2 = []
    prev = difflib.Match(0,0,0)
    for match in difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=l1, b=l2).get_matching_blocks():
        if (prev.a + prev.size != match.a):
            for i in range(prev.a + prev.size, match.a):
                res2 += ['_' * len(l1[i])]
            res1 += l1[prev.a + prev.size:match.a]
        if (prev.b + prev.size != match.b):
            for i in range(prev.b + prev.size, match.b):
                res1 += ['_' * len(l2[i])]
            res2 += l2[prev.b + prev.size:match.b]
        res1 += l1[match.a:match.a+match.size]
        res2 += l2[match.b:match.b+match.size]
        prev = match
    return untokenize(res1), untokenize(res2)
    print(untokenize(res1), untokenize(res2))
```

This is the output from that code on the example string:
('this is a test _______', 'this is a ____ testing')

But I want to apply this is to a pandas dataframe across two different columns and return a new column with the result.

Comment: You can use pandas .apply to form the new column using your function. It is rather slow for large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try-

```
# Assuming your dataframe name to be "df"
df['colC'] = df.apply(lambda row: equalize(row['ColA'], row['ColB']),axis=1)
```

Note - setting the axis=1 would help you access the respective columns of a single row. Find more about pandas apply [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).